# Using the cut() method in java

Tags: java, string, copy-paste

I would like to implement the cut method in java to provide the cut and paste functionality.I have already used StringSelection and getSystemClipboard() to provide the cut functionality(code below),but I wanna know how I can use java's inbuilt cut() method for it.
 Code for cut functionality.

```
String t = qu.getText();
        StringSelection s = new StringSelection(t);
        this.getToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(s, s);
        qu.setText("");
```

I expected something like this to work but it didn't

```
        qu.cut();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"Sample code would be really helpful."` -- you first. Consider posting your [sscce](http://sscce.org) that we can work with. Also are you coding within a certain GUI library such as Swing? SWT? Other? More information would really be nice.

Comment: the variable name for my text field is qu.so I expected                          qu.cut() to work but it didn't

Comment: `I expected qu.cut() to work but it didn't` - We can't offer any advice based on a single line of code. You have been asked to post a SSCCE.

Comment: what is `qu`? Object of which class?

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because cut() method requires a selection in the text field. Try the following code:

```
qu.selectAll();
qu.cut();
```

Answer (score 3):

If Swing just use the Actions available from the DefaultEditorKit:

```
new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction()
```

For example, a small program that uses default actions in a menu, a component-specific pop-up menu, and in buttons:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TestActions {
   private String[] texts = {
         "Hello", "Goodbye", "What the f***?", "Heck if I know", "Peace out man!"
   };
   private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
   private Action[] textActions = { new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction(),
         new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction(), new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction(), };
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
   private JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
   private PopupListener popupListener = new PopupListener();

   public TestActions() {
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
      JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");
      for (Action textAction : textActions) {
         btnPanel.add(new JButton(textAction));
         menu.add(new JMenuItem(textAction));
         popup.add(new JMenuItem(textAction));
      }
      menubar.add(menu);

      JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
      for (String text: texts) {
         JTextField textField = new JTextField(text, 15);
         textField.addMouseListener(popupListener);
         textFieldPanel.add(textField);
         textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
               ((JTextComponent)e.getSource()).selectAll();
            }
         });
      }
      textArea.addMouseListener(popupListener);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

      JPanel textFieldPanelWrapper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      textFieldPanelWrapper.add(textFieldPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      mainPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      mainPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      mainPanel.add(textFieldPanelWrapper, BorderLayout.EAST);
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
      return menubar;
   }

   private class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         maybeShowPopup(e);
     }

     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         maybeShowPopup(e);
     }

     private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
             popup.show(e.getComponent(),
                        e.getX(), e.getY());
         }
     }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestActions testActions = new TestActions();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Actions");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(testActions.getMainPanel());
      frame.setJMenuBar(testActions.getMenuBar());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to use the cut() method?

Comment: +1, Why do you think you need to use the cut() method directly? Swing was designed to be used with Actions. You just add the Action to a JMenuItem or JButton and your cut problem is solved. By the way the CutAction does use the cut() method.

Comment: @Omiye Jay Jay first select some text in qu before using built in cut() method. I would suggest to use `qu.selectAll();` before calling the `qu.cut();` method.